# Restore RDS Master username of native backup on new RDS instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I created a RDS SQL Server web instance and restored native backup from Standard edition SQL Server instance. Both are using different usernames.

I have a RDS SQL Server Express edition server which I wanted to move to RDS SQL Server Web edition. So I created a new instance and restored native backup from Express edition instance to Web edition RDS instance. However, I can not use master username of previous Express edition instance on web edition instance. I have tried resetting permissions or updating password but I get an error:

```
1> sp_helpuser;
2> go


UserName                                                           RoleName         LoginName                                                          DefDBName    DefSchemaName UserID     SID                                                                                                                                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------ ------------ ------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
##MS_AgentSigningCertificate##                                     public           ##MS_AgentSigningCertificate##                                     master       NULL          6          0x010600A06045EF23                                                                                                          
##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##                                  public           ##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##                                  master       dbo           5          0x45932F8072F                                                                                                                                          
dbo                                                                db_owner         rdsa                                                               master       dbo           1          0x01                                                                                                                                                                        
guest                                                              public           NULL                                                               NULL         guest         2          0x00                                                                                                                                                                        
INFORMATION_SCHEMA                                                 public           NULL                                                               NULL         NULL          3          NULL                                                                                                                                                                        
sys                                                                public           NULL                                                               NULL         NULL          4          NULL
```

---

```
1> SELECT name FROM sys.databases;
2> 
3> go
name                                                                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
master                                                                                                                          
tempdb                                                                                                                          
model                                                                                                                           
msdb                                                                                                                            
rdsadmin                                                                                                                        
testdb
```

How can I use user from my express edition in web edition after restoring native backup?